# XSLT - Saxon error on updating from 9.4.0-9 to 9.7.0-14

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

In my xslt 
I got follow error when I update Saxon version from 9.4.0-9 to 9.7.0-14.

net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Required item type of result of call to collection is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

Whats the issue here ?

```
<xsl:variable name="file-uris" as="xs:string*"
  select="if (empty($symbol.mappings.folder.uri)) then () else
     for $f in collection(concat($symbol.mappings.folder.uri, '?select=*.txt&amp;unparsed=yes'))
  return string($f/base-uri())"/>
```

Comment: I can't find the `unparsed` parameter in the Saxon 9.7 doc about collections, I am not sure that is the reason for the error you say you get. If the aim is to read out the URIs of the text files in a certain folder then with Saxon 9.7 in a `version="3.0"` stylesheet it might suffice to use `<xsl:variable name="file-uris" as="xs:string*" select="if (empty($symbol.mappings.folder.uri)) then () else uri-collection(concat($symbol.mappings.folder.uri, '?select=*.txt'))"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but thats not the case.

Comment: I m using xslt 2.0. My consultant said, its the problem with collection function. I mean, Saxon 9.4.x to 9.7x its collection function definitions might be changed.

Comment: Yes, see the documentation on the saxonica.com site, it explains a change to the collection function, for instance the `unparsed` parameter is no longer mentioned there, but as said, I don't know whether that explains the error. I guess you have to be patient until Michael Kay comes along and can tell you more details.

Answer (score 0):

There have been substantial changes to the collection() function in Saxon 9.7, triggered by changes to the spec in XPath 3.0 and 3.1 - unfortunately the generalisation to collections of any kind of resource (e.g. JSON files) made it very hard to retain 100% backwards compatibility.

The specific issue here is that with the "unparsed" option, earlier Saxon releases anticipated a way of handling non-document collections that proved incompatible with the way the specs subsequently evolved. The specific error occurs if collection() returns non-node values when XPath 3.0 is not enabled, because Saxon is now trying to comply with both the 2.0 and 3.0 rules depending which version of XSLT/XPath is active. With 3.0 enabled, and with default configuration settings, the file extension ".txt" is enough to cause resources in a collection to be returned as instances of xs:string, but this doesn't work if 3.0 is not enabled.

(A procedural note: you're welcome to raise Saxon questions here, but we find it easier to track them if you raise them on the support site at saxonica.plan.io - if you raise a question there then we try to ensure that it is closed with a satisfactory resolution, whereas with questions raised here it's more hit-and-miss.)